# Is Spec# stable enough to use?

Tags: c#-4.0, design-by-contract, spec#

Does anyone here use Spec# regularly? I would like to know if it is stable and powerful enough before I start using it everywhere.
It looks like the syntax is influencing c# 4.0, which will hopefully make it easier to upgrade once 4.0 is released. Thoughts?

Comment: Use everywhere? Only if it's documented you should take that route. Clearly it's not the case, which signals it's an experimental/research-oriented in-house product. Spec#, Sing#, C-omega, F* there are quite a few like this. On the other hand to try something out Nemerle or Boo will be better alternatives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you mean by "stable". There are two possible interpretations:

1. "not crashing"
2. "not changing"

I don't know about #1, but if you mean #2, then, well, [Spec#](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/SpecSharp/) has been abandoned and is no longer being developed, so that's probably as stable as you're gonna get.

The techniques and tools that were used in [Spec#](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/SpecSharp/) (the static analysis tool called [Boogie](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/Boogie/) and the theorem prover / constraint solver [Z3](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/projects/z3/)) are now part of a new library called [Code Contracts for .NET](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/Contracts/). The upshot of being a library is that Code Contracts will work for *any* .NET language: C#, VB.NET, F#, Ruby, Python, JavaScript, Lisp, Smalltalk, Boo, you name it. The downside is that you get no language integration, so no nice syntax for contracts.

Code Contracts for .NET will be part of .NET 4.0 / Visual Studio 2010, but unfortunately there will be no DbC support in any of Microsoft's languages.

Comment: So what makes you say that Spec# was abandoned? I can find no reference to this...

Comment: I don't remember whether I heard that on a podcast, a Channel 9 video or maybe a blog post. Basically, nobody is working on Spec# anymore, because they all work full-time on the Code Contracts.NET library now. There might be bugfixes and maintenance releases for Spec#, but there won't be any ...

Comment: ... further development, there won't be a production release (currently it is illegal to use Spec# for commercial projects), and there most certainly won't be any C# 3.0 or C# 4.0 features. All the technology that was developed for Spec# is now in Code Contracts.

Comment: Also, there has been no release since 2007.

Comment: The relationship is explained a little bit here: http://Research.Microsoft.Com/Contracts/faq.aspx