# What tooling do you use to do Design by Contract?

Tags: .net, code-contracts, design-by-contract, microsoft-contracts

I used to use [Microsoft CodeContracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) for three weeks and now half of my code is just contracts. I have dozens of unproved places, I cannot use runtime-check because IL rewrite prevents coverage tool to show something and compile time is less then acceptable.

I do not like this. And seems now is a good time to ask a help. What tooling do use use for your regualr developments?

Answer (score 2):

[Spec#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/) -  I have not tried it myself, but I hear it is pretty awesome.  There is a good DotNetRocks podcast on it that is a good listen on the drive to work.

Comment: You probably want to read [Is Spec# stable enough to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437383/is-spec-stable-enough-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

I use Visual Studio 2010 with code contracts.  And I work on a daily basis with a solution that has 20 large projects in it. Yes, the runtime checks slow down the compile time. But I accept the penalty to achieve more reliable code. I notice your message was posted in Jan 2010. It is over a year later, and you may find the latest release of Code Contracts rewriter is somewhat faster. But do not expect a miracle there.

Also, they have improved how code coverage reports on code where code contracts are used. So if that is the point that bothers you most, definitely try again with the latest version.