# What is Spec# I've been hearing about?

Tags: .net, spec#

What is Spec# I've been hearing about?

Answer (score 4):

> Spec# is a formal language for API
>   contracts (influenced by JML, AsmL,
>   and Eiffel), which extends C# with
>   constructs for non-null types,
>   preconditions, postconditions, and
>   object invariants. Spec# comes with a
>   sound programming methodology that
>   permits specification and reasoning
>   about object invariants even in the
>   presence of callbacks and
>   multi-threading. Spec# is a research
>   vehicle that has been used to explore
>   specifications and the dynamic/static
>   tools that make use of them.

More in [Spec#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/)

Comment: It should be.  It's a cut and paste from the posted link.

Comment: I figured as much... but that doesn't stop it from be a great description

Answer (score 4):

Spec# is programming language that is essential an extension to C#. It adds the ability to define contracts on methods. Contacts are conditions that **must** be true for the method to be valid. An example of a contact would be stating that a specific parameter must not be null when the method is run.

It includes a tool that can be run that attempts to prove if the conditions are guaranteed to be met.

It was a research project by Microsoft that has now been abandoned, but the work that was done forms the basis of the [code contracts in .net 4.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/11/08/code-contracts-for-net-4-0-spec-comes-alive.aspx).

[Spec# on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spec_Sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Check out  Microsoft's site on the language http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Microsoft Research page](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/) outlining the project.

From the site:

> The Spec# programming system is a new
>   attempt at a more cost effective way
>   to develop and maintain high-quality
>   software.

Answer (score 1):

Spec# is a research language involving Design by Contract.

Note that Microsoft has chosen to integrate Code Contracts into the upcoming .NET Framework 4.0 Release.  More info:

http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/11/08/code-contracts-for-net-4-0-spec-comes-alive.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's been abandoned.

[Is Spec# stable enough to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437383/is-spec-stable-enough-to-use)

Comment: While this maybe true... it doesn't really answer the question.